# Purple screen of death after login

Tags: 18.04, crash, plymouth, recovery-mode

I've been using Ubuntu on this machine for over a year but since yesterday I can't get past the purple screen that appears after I insert my credentials.

I've tried to use `nomodeset` but it didn't help. I tried to remove `quiet splash`, also didn't help. I tried `apt-get update` from the terminal (recovery mode) but it didn't work. I also tried other options available in recovery mode but to no avail.

My specs are:

- CPU: Intel Core i5-4690
- MOTHERBOARD: MSI - Z97
- MEMORY: Corsair Vengeance Pro 16GB x 2
- VIDEO CARD: MSI Radeon R9 280

I use Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Comment: I would suggest switching to a terminal (ctrl+alt+f4 for example) and login there.  Check you have some free space in $HOME (ie. `df -hl` or disk-free) as GUI or desktops create workfiles during login, if they can't be created (due to lack of space, permissions etc) you get logged out & returned to greeter (so you can login again).  If you have no space, or very little space, you need to delete some space in $HOME (your user directory)

Comment: @guiverc Can confirm I do have enough space.